# how to position links at the bottom in a fixed height list

Tags: css

I would like to have a menu with an height of 100px with separators. I've put my menu in a unordered list and added a border-right to the li. So far so good but I can't find how to align my links at the bottom ?

HTML

```
<div id="menu">
   <ul>
      <li id="logo"></li>
      <li><a href="#item-1" class="first">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#item-2">Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#item-3">Item 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#item-4">Item 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#item-5">Item 5</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#menu {
    background:#5a5a5a;
    height:100px;
    left:0px;
    position:fixed;
    top:50px;
    width:100%;
}
#menu ul {
    list-style-image: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin:0px;
}
#menu li {
    border-right:1px solid #c6c6c6;
    display:inline-block;
    height:100px;
}
#menu ul li a {
    color:#fff;
    line-height:100px;
    margin:0 10px;
    padding:0 15px;
    text-decoration:none;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
#menu ul li a:hover {
    background:#c6c6c6;
    color:#fff;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You want the `a` to be aligned to the bottom of the parent `li`?

Comment: Yes. I would like the text Item-1 to be at the bottom of the li.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've always disliked the `inline-block` method, so I'm using floats for this instead. See if this is what you want (I've taken the liberty of making the anchors expand out to the size of the list items). http://jsfiddle.net/gSMVA/

The code:

```
#menu {
    background: #5a5a5a;
    height: 100px;
    left: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}

#menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
}

#menu li {
    border-right: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
}

#menu ul li a {
    color:#fff;
    padding: 0 25px;
    height: 100px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration:none;

    /* Height * 2 - font size */
    line-height: 188px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

#menu ul li a:hover {
    background: #c6c6c6;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#menu li {
    border-right:1px solid #c6c6c6;
    display:inline-block;
    height:20px;
    padding-top:80px
}
#menu ul li a {
    color:#fff;
    line-height:20px;
    margin:0 10px;
    padding:0 15px;
    text-decoration:none;
```